# Insert multiple enteries into one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to add multiple entries into one column and single entries in other columns?

For example

```
$sql="INSERT INTO The_table (firstname, lastname, address) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[address]'";
```

Then I have multiple checkbox entries I need to insert - age, shirt size, height in one column called about.

How would I write the $sql statement?

Comment: You can try to insert age, shirt size, height as comma separated in one column

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO? Please tell me you're not using mysql_* functions in PHP...

Comment: I'm using mysqli... Is it possible for someone to answer the question asked?

Comment: Please do not do that. Use three separate columns.

Comment: What's the problem with putting a comment with several pieces of information in a single column? It gives the user a starting point for their "about" for their profile which they can then edit as they wish... Not sure if this is what the OP is using it for, but there are plenty of times when that would be a very viable solution.

Comment: Tarik using one column works very well.  Why would someone want to have over 20 columns when they can reduce it down by adding certain entries that go together in one column.  Pretty simple!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option (other than the CONCAT mentioned), is to create composite variables in PHP.

For instance,

```
$about = $_POST['about1'] . ', ' . $_POST['about2'];
```

and then in your query you could do something like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO The_table (firstname, lastname, address) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[address]', '$about'";
```

If you don't know how many different entries there will be in in `$about`, then you could create something in your form grab the data with a `foreach` statement such as

```
foreach ($_POST['about'] as $about) { etc.  }
```

and you've named your variable in the form like this.

```
<input type="text" name="about[]" />
```

if your "about variable is a textarea then this:

```
<textarea name='about[]'></textarea>
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around your `$about` in the query.

Comment: Thanks nomistic I will not know how many entries will be in $about.  Can you explain your code foreach ($_POST['about'] as $about) { etc.  }  what code goes in { }

Comment: Actually I got it to work.  Thank you for your help.... I very much appreciate it.  Please do me a favor and this goes for others too.  Stop with the etc and/or ...... explain what goes in the bracket or where ever so people can learn.  Not asking you to write it for everyone but rather not all of us will know what goes in certain places and using etc and ...... does NOT help.

Comment: sorry, I just got back to this now.  I was simply answering your original question  without going into a tangent (which tends to be the norm here I've learned).    Anyway I'm very glad you got it to work :)  (as an FYI, people on SO generally don't like to write people's code for them, but will happily point you in directions which can help solve a problem.  It is generally the approach to encourage people to learn on their own, which is exactly what you did! :) )

Answer (score 3):

You can very easily concatenate a string in PHP which will then be put into the SQL insert query.

```
$about = "AGE: $_POST[age]\nSHIRT SIZE: $_POST[shirt_size]\nHEIGHT: $_POST[height]";
$sql = "INSERT INTO The_table (firstname, lastname, address, about) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[address]', '$about')";
```

Of course you should be preparing your statement and using appropriate bind values instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO The_table (firstname, lastname, address, about) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
// now prepare, bind and execute
```

If you don't do the prepare/bind stuff then you are asking for problems security wise. At the very least you need to apply appropriate escaping mechanisms to the user-supplied data.

Copying the example from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php and modifying it for you:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Prepare an insert statement */
$query = "INSERT INTO The_table (firstname, lastname, address, about) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['first'], $_POST['last'], $_POST['address'], $about);

/* here's where you do your special assignments */
$about = "AGE: $_POST[age]\nSHIRT SIZE: $_POST[shirt_size]\nHEIGHT: $_POST[height]";    

/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: But if you had a DB why would you want to do this rather than put separate types of data in separate columns?

Comment: Can you write out the // now prepare, bind and execute so I can see it and understand what you're saying?

Comment: What goes here >  "ssss".   Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: I would put "ssss" there. You need to look up these functions (get used to typing php.net in your browser!) and get familiar with them, but what this says is that these 4 variables are all strings (as opposed to numbers or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function CONCAT

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat
```

I don't have a mysql server to test it but I think this is a good approach to do that.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO The_table (firstname, lastname, address, about) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[address]', CONCAT('$_POST[age]', ' ', '$_POST[shirtSize]', ' ', '$_POST[height]')";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your fields using PHP concat function.

```
$about="$age|$shirt_size|$height";
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname, address, about) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$address', '$about')";
```

And to retrieve the same from the database,
use explode function in PHP.

```
$about=explode('|',$result['about']);
$age=$about[0];
$shirt_size=$about[1];
$height=$about[2];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can separating your entries by pipe or another thing.

Such as:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `The_table` (`firstname`,`lastname`,`address`,`info`) VALUES ('{$_POST[firstname]}','{$_POST[lastname]}','{$_POST[address]}','Red|XXL|50')";
```

Comment: 'another thing'? What kind of other thing?

Comment: OP is getting his data from $_POST - your answer should reflect that rather than hardcoding a string.